# How to create mysql table in php using class(oops) in php?

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, create-table

I need to create a MySQL table using classes in PHP 
I am using following code but no table is being created

```
<?php
$this->query("
   CREATE TABLE '$table2'(
messageno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(messageno),
 user_id VARCHAR, message VARCHAR,message_time DATETIME)");


?>

<?php 
class core {



public function __construct() {
      $this->db = new mysqli('localhost','box','box','box');
}

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    } 

}
?>
```

So, please suggest the change or the appropriate way to create a table

I am just a beginner, so sorry if I am asking this simple question.

Comment: It's not a bad question, but it's not specific enough, why don't you look into PHP OOP tutorials instead of asking a question here?

Comment: in the query you have `$table2` and before that you define `$table` I think these should be the same.

Comment: Does you mysql user have create privileges?

Comment: What is the context of the code where you are running the query, is that in a method in the class `db` belongs to? And you should display errors during development and add error handling, especially for the database operations.

Comment: @jeroen i just added that bit of code in above question please check

Comment: did you check the mysql_error from your query?  It can tell you a lot.

Comment: i used it sir but no help @jeroen

Answer (score 0):

You define `$table` in your example as `no_name`.  But then you seem to be using `$table2` in your query.  Where is that defined?

Should it be:

```
$table = 'no_name';
$query = "CREATE TABLE {$table} ( 
    messageno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(messageno),
 user_id VARCHAR, message VARCHAR,message_time DATETIME)";

$this->query( $query );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some form of error handling to figure out what's going on

```
public function query($sql) {
  if (($result = $this->db->query($sql)) !== false) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($this->db));
  }
}
```